# Hibernate's session calls disconnect() method. After that, I want to restore the connection again and cannot find the corresponding API

Tags: java, hibernate

### Hibernate's session calls disconnect() method. After that, I want to restore the connection again and cannot find the corresponding API.

- What should I do to restore the connection?
- Why is session.isOpen() result still true, after I call disconnect().
- Why is session.isConnected() still true, after I call disconnect().

  ```
  public void disconnect(){
          session.disconnect();
          System.out.println(session.isOpen());//true
          System.out.println(session.isConnected());//true
  }
  ```
- Could somebody tell me?
- Thank you for!

Comment: you need to put the code what you are trying with

Comment: I tried to use doWork() Method,but it need Work instance as parameter,and I don't know how to instance Work class,so I can not put the code.